# MacPorts thinks I'm in Europe?

Tags: config, macports, mirror

It seems that no matter what I do, I can not get my MacPorts to connect to a US server.

```
--->  Attempting to fetch mongodb-2.4.10_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/mongodb
--->  Attempting to fetch mongodb-2.4.10_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/mongodb
--->  Attempting to fetch mongodb-2.4.10_0.darwin_13.x86_64.tbz2 from http://nue.de.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/mongodb
--->  Fetching distfiles for mongodb
--->  Attempting to fetch mongodb-src-r2.4.10.tar.gz from http://sea.us.distfiles.macports.org/macports/distfiles/mongodb
--->  Attempting to fetch mongodb-src-r2.4.10.tar.gz from http://cjj.kr.distfiles.macports.org/mongodb
```

My sources.conf file only contains one line:

```
# For proper functionality of various resources (port groups, mirror
# sites, etc.), the primary MacPorts source must always be tagged
# "[default]", even if switched from the default "rsync://" URL.

# rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar [default]
rsync://sea.us.rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar [default]
```

And inside my macports.conf I have:

`rsync_server            sea.us.rsync.macports.org`

Any one have any clues?